# How to pass a variable to a function in this example?

Tags: python, function

I wrote a very basic script to cleanup my downloads folder and everything worked fine, but I was not using any functions.

To clean things up a bit and make it more organized, I tried to create functions and pass the directory path as a variable "cleaningpath", but I think I am doing something incorrect.

```
import sys
import os
from os import listdir
from os.path import join
import shutil


#Variables
path="/Users/OwlFace/downloads"
cleaningpath=os.listdir(path)


def deleterars(cleaningpath):
    rarcounter=0
    for item in cleaningpath:
        if item.endswith(".rar"):
            os.remove(join(cleaningpath,item))
            rarcounter+=1
    print "you have succesfully removed", rarcounter, "rar files"


def organizemusic(cleaningpath):
    mp3counter=0
    if not os.path.exists("/Users/OwlFace/downloads/NewMusic/"):
        os.makedirs("/Users/OwlFace/downloads/NewMusic/")
    mp3folder="/Users/OwlFace/downloads/NewMusic/"

    for item in cleaningpath:
        if item.endswith(".mp3"):
            location1 = join(cleaningpath,item)
            location2 = join(mp3folder,item)
            shutil.move(location1, location2)
            mp3counter+=1
    print "you have succesfully moved", mp3counter, "mp3's to the music folder"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    deleterars(cleaningpath)
    organizemusic(cleaning path)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cleaningscript.py", line 39, in <module>
    organizemusic(cleaningpath)
  File "cleaningscript.py", line 30, in organizemusic
    location1 = join(cleaningpath,item)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/posixpath.py", line 70, in join
    elif path == '' or path.endswith('/'):
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'endswith'
```

Comment: What exactly is not working?  Any error messages?

Comment: I think you trying to `.join` the list variable instead of the name of directory path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error refers to the line:

```
    location1 = join(cleaningpath,item)
```

This line doesn't work because `cleaningpath` is a list of file names, not a string. I think you want your global variable `path` as the first argument to `join`.

You have the same issue in your other function, on this line:

```
            os.remove(join(cleaningpath,item))
```

Comment: And I should probably not name it "cleaningpath"